# Why don't i get Newsletter subscribe action Url in form in my custom .phtml file

Tags: template, custom, phtml, newsletter, magento-2.0.2

I am just wondering why i am **not getting the action Url in my Newsletter Subscribe form**. I am calling the newsletter subscription form in my custom phtml file. I do get the form but when i inspect element the form action remains empty.

I am using the same code which is in `subscribe.phtml`

P.S I am calling the block like this in my custom phtml file.

```
include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Newsletter::custom_subscribe.phtml'))
```

The `custom_subscribe.phtml` is my custom file with just change in style as i didn't tweak the main phtml.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same problem and fixed by changing code in cms home page

Find this line :

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

and change it to :

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Then define block in

```
 System > Permissions > Blocks
```

here add new block in this name **newsletter/subscribe**

After done above all you can get action url in newsletter form.
Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your block is not extending the `Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe` block.

The native subscribe template retrieves the form action URL by calling the following code:

```
$block->getFormActionUrl()
```

This method is declared in the block:

```
public function getFormActionUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', ['_secure' => true]);
}
```

Thus, if your block does not extend the original block this method cannot be called.

Comment: how can i extend my block? I am using custom custom block like this    <container name="custom.footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom_footer" after="main.content">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mainfooter" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer_row.phtml">

                </block>

               
            </container> In this phtml i am calling the newsletter block